# Can I make a split and filter inside one single stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to do the following....

I have a list of string in the following mode:

```
John,Peter,Carl
Rose,Joanne,Natalie
```

At the moment I am reading line by line and outputting a stream...

Like this:

```
 Files.lines(myfile).toURI()))
```

This returns a stream.

I know I can collect them into a list but I am wondering if inside this stream I can split and do some more logic?

I try to split each line and filter in case any of the three expected fields is empty, is it possible?

At the moment I have it in the "old way" like this:

```
List<TripleNames> validValues = new ArrayList();
for(String value:values) { //values represent each line comma separated
   final String[] names = line.split(",");
   if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(names[0]) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(names[1]).... {
    validValues.add(new TripleNames(names[0], names[1], names[2]);
   } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for `map`ping before collecting to a List as :

```
List<TripleNames> validValues = values.stream()
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .filter(names -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(names[0]) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(names[1]))
        .map(names -> new TripleNames(names[0], names[1], names[2]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You also need to check `names[2]` for _blankness_. You can use `StringUtils#isNoneBlank` to check all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way to check all splitted items, you can use:

```
Arrays.stream(names).allMatch(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
```

Instead of checking each each item separately in a condition.

Here is the full example:

```
List<String> validValues = values.stream()
    .map(line -> line.split(","))
    .filter(names -> Arrays.stream(names).allMatch(StringUtils::isNotBlank))
    .map(names -> new TripleNames(names[0], names[1], names[2]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You also can use `.map(String::trim)` before `.allMatch()` to to cut of white spaces at the beginning and the end of all names, if that helps.